# Magento 2: Radio option not sending the data on form submit in admin panel

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

Hi am using the following code to set the radio box value. But it is not working, Where as other form fields are working fine.

**Code**

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'gender',
            'radios',
            [
                'label' => __('Gender'),
                'title' => __('Gender'),
                'name' => 'gender',
                'required' => false,
                'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'male','label'=>'Male'),
                        array('value'=>'female','label'=>'Female'),
                   )

            ]
        );
```

**Code 2:**

```
if (isset($postData['gender'])) 
     {
        echo 'is set'.$postData['gender'];
        exit();
     }
else {
        echo 'Not set';
        exit();
     }
```

It echo **$$$** instead the gender value, when selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the complete code with form?

Comment: Other form fields are working fine. This one is have the problem

Comment: frontend or adminpanel?

Comment: Admin panel form

Comment: can you add save controller so i can check ? you can also check `print_r($postData);` that values is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the **posted values** you can simply get it by below code

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
print_r($data); // this will show all the post values 
echo $data['gender']; //this will give you geneder field value
```